# read pdf in php embeded

Tags: php, html, pdf, embed

I am developing a web site in php I want to show a PDF file in my website. I am found this code :

```
$file = 'Digital.pdf';
$filename = 'Digital.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline;    filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile($file);
```

when I use this code I have a message box from IDM show to Download the file. Not only this code I have same issue when I use iframe tage. How to fix this ?

Comment: use `<iframe>`. its helps you

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<iframe src="./my/folder/path/<?php echo $file ?>"></iframe>
```

You can use these atributes

1. Width
2. Height
3. sandbox
4. srcdoc

[HTML `<iframe>` Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Comment: when I use iframe tag I have same issue

Comment: it will load pdf in in-line

Comment: no i have a message box from IDM for download. the file not display in browser.